# Failed to set response header in postHandle interceptor

Tags: spring-boot

Recently I try to add a response header in `postHander` interceptor

```java
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("preHandle");
        response.setHeader("aaa","aaa");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);

        response.setHeader("bbb","bbb");
        System.out.println("postHandler");
    }
```

this is my main code, but when I send a request to server, only `aaa` was added to response header.

[image]

But console still log

```
preHandle
postHandler
```

It means the `postHandle` is actually executed, but do not add the header.

Why? how to fix this problem?

Comment: Did my solution not help you?

Comment: @bytefish - is this solved? if yes, can you please add the answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example. If I had to guess its someting thats happening in

```
super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);
```

Web Config

```
@Component
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new CustomHandleInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Interceptor

```
@Component
public class CustomHandleInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        response.setHeader("pre","works");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        response.setHeader("post","works");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
        response.setHeader("complete","works");
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {
    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingMethod(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "greeting";
    }
}
```

Response Headers

```
$ curl -I  http://localhost:8080/greeting
HTTP/1.1 200 
pre: works
post: works
complete: works
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Length: 212
Date: Fri, 15 Mar 2019 01:42:08 GMT
```

Comment: I am using like this only, but still same issue is there. Not able to set response headers in postHandle, but able to set in preHandle.

Comment: @Jason - same here! I tried the same but did not work for me!